# Position image in Grid with ZIndex

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an image on top of a button that is on a grid. I want to place the image behind the button when I click on the button "Hide Image". I have tried with Panel.ZIndex, but apparently it is not available for Grid.

```
  <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="201,79,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="btn_1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Panel.ZIndex="-1"/>
        <Image Source="Max_dog.png" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>

        <Button x:Name="btn_2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn_3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn_4" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
    <Button Content="Button"  Margin="215,205,228.667,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to do this in WPF is to have a [view model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798384.aspx) that you attach to the data context of the window or a control. Then you bind a property of the view model to the `Visibility` property of the image.

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _isImageVisible;
    public bool IsImageVisible
    {
        get { return _isImageVisible; }
        set {
            if (value != _isImageVisible) {
                _isImageVisible = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ImageVisibility));
            }
        }
    }

    public Visibility ImageVisibility => _isImageVisible
        ? Visibility.Visible
        : Visibility.Hidden; // or Collapsed

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

In XAML

```
<Image Source="Max_dog.png" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
    Visibility="{Binding ImageVisibility}"/>
```

Not that you cannot bind the `Visibility` property to a Boolean. Therefore I made two properties a Boolean property that you can easily set and another one exposing the required [`Visibility`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visibility(v=vs.110).aspx) enum.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        btn_1.SetValue(Panel.ZIndexProperty, 3);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

WPF forms the controls in the layout on stack. The item lower in the stack will always have lower zIndex compared to item on higher position. The solution here to change the declaration of statements to

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="201,79,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Image Source="Max_dog.png" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn_1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn_2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn_3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn_4" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
    <Button Content="Button"  Margin="215,205,228.667,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>
```

See the declaration of button and image has been reversed.